# GZipStream, how correctly read from GZipStream

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, memorystream, networkstream

I have some code writen by me in C#

```
        string host = new Uri(_url).Host;
        IPHostEntry ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress.AddressList[0], 80);
        using (Socket s = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            s.Connect(ip);
            using (NetworkStream n = new NetworkStream(s))
            {
                    byte[] write = encoding.GetBytes(HttpQuery);
                    n.Write(write, 0, write.Length);
                    ReadLine(n);
                    Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    while (true)
                    {
                        string line = ReadLine(n);
                        if (line.Length == 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        int index = line.IndexOf(':');
                        if (!headers.ContainsKey(line.Substring(0, index)))
                        {
                            headers.Add(line.Substring(0, index), line.Substring(index + 2));
                        }
                    }

                    string contentEncoding;
                    if (headers.TryGetValue("Content-Encoding", out contentEncoding))
                    {
                        Stream responseStream = n;
                        if (contentEncoding.Equals("gzip"))
                        {
                            responseStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                            responseStream.Flush();
                        }
                        else if (contentEncoding.Equals("deflate"))
                        {
                            responseStream = new DeflateStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                        }

                        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

                        byte[] respBuffer = new byte[4096];
                        try
                        {
                            int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(respBuffer, 0, respBuffer.Length);
                            //int bytesRead = responseStream.ReadByte();
                            while (bytesRead > 0)
                            {
                                memStream.Write(respBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                bytesRead = responseStream.Read(respBuffer, 0, respBuffer.Length);
                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            responseStream.Close();
                        }
                        string str = encoding.GetString(memStream.ToArray());
```

Then I Have an exception InvalidDataException in this line **int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(respBuffer, 0, respBuffer.Length);**

GZip header magic number is not correct.

```
    string ReadLine(Stream stream)
    {
        List<byte> lineBuffer = new List<byte>();
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int b = stream.ReadByte();
                if (b == -1)
                    return null;
                if (b == 10)
                    break;
                if (b != 13)
                    lineBuffer.Add((byte) b);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return encoding.GetString(lineBuffer.ToArray());
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Avoid inventing the wheel, the HttpWebResponse class already does this.

Answer (score 0):

Your ReadLine function returns as soon as it reads one line feed character when reading a blank line.  Doesn't that potentially leave the stream positioned at a carriage return character instead of at the beginning of the GZip data stream?

Answer (score 0):

in general, I found something on the subject, here's [Sockets in C#: How to get the response stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523930/sockets-in-c-how-to-get-the-response-stream) link, there is some information that before the string (s) to do so:

```
                        Stream responseStream = n;
                        int magicNumber = 0;
                        while (magicNumber != 10)
                        {
                            magicNumber = responseStream.ReadByte();
                        }
                        if (contentEncoding.Equals("gzip"))
                        {
                            responseStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                        }
```

perhaps I did not quite do it correctly?

**nobugz**
I have very succeful code writen with WttWebRequest and HttpWebResponse, **BUT** my page have codepape-1251, and HttpWebRequest convert url from 1251 encoding to UTF-8 I and nothing  can do with this, maybe you have any ideas?

For example I have url as *[http://myurl.php?name=Мастер%20Создатель](http://myurl.php?name=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)*

**HttpWebRequest** convert this in *http://myurl.php?name=%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80+%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c* (UTF-8)

BUT will be *http://myurl.php?name=%CC%E0%F1%F2%E5%F0%20%D1%EE%E7%E4%E0%F2%E5%EB%FC*(windows-1251), I don't know how fix this

Comment: Why is the encoding of the URL a problem?  You're trying to process gzip content in the response, not the URL, right?  Is this question related to your original question somehow?