# HTTP GET request and XML answer

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, I need to send HTTP GET request and read answer. I am familiar with  Java and easy can do it URLConnection class but I don't know in c#. Can anybody help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523930/sockets-in-c-how-to-get-the-response-stream

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The *simplest* way is to use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string text = client.DownloadString(url);
```

(That's the synchronous form; it also supports asynchronous requests.)

For more control you might want to use [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).