# httpwebrequest order of request

Tags: c#, .net, http, http-headers

I am using HttpWebRequest to send requests in c#

The request should be like this:

```
POST https://website.com/file HTTP/1.1
Host: api.website.com
User-Agent: useragent
Content-Length: 81
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

but it is showing like this:

```
POST https://website.com/file HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5
User-Agent: useragent
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: api.website.com
Content-Length: 97
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I tried to search on how to change order of httpwebrequest but could not find anything.

Comment: If your server depends on the orders of the *headers*, I'd argue it's broken. I wouldn't *expect* the order to be guaranteed or meaningful - why is your code sensitive to it?

Comment: you wont to change order of headers ? Why is that important ?

Comment: the web server has a security check to check the order of the headers. so i have to keep them that way.

Comment: Show them this part of the RFC: [_" The order in which header fields with differing field names are received is not significant."_](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-32).

Comment: Duplicate of [Is it possible to change headers order using HttpWebRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521977/is-it-possible-to-change-headers-order-using-httpwebrequest), where the answer is: no, if you really need this, write a HTTP client yourself using sockets.

Comment: hmm, yea the writing http client using sockets is my option, but trying to find if there is anything less time consuming. Is there any open source http client source that i can modify to my needs ?

Comment: @circler: Probably not.  There might be clients which coincidentally maintain the order of headers, but it's unlikely that any of them *guarantee* the order of headers.  Since this is custom functionality that's not part of the standard, you're looking at writing a custom implementation.